# Change from http to https in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset in a machine Centos 7 Minimal, but I don´t know how to change from http to https in the configuration file.

I have changed some values in path **/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/config.py** but I have the same result.

Comment: Please specify more specifically what configuration changes you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lets Encrypt, a free SSL certificate

1. Install Certbot using this command

   sudo yum install certbot python2-certbot-apache
2. Run this command to get a certificate

   sudo certbot --apache
3. Setup automatic renewal of the certificate using this command

   echo "0 0,12 * * * root python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && certbot renew -q" | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab > /dev/null
4. Confirm if certbot worked by accessing your site through https

Finally  redirect your superset to https.

Comment: Sorry I am new with superset, how you can configure superset from http to https?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to connect to superset with https, since I didn’t know the exact command to do it, but I finally discovered it. The command would be "superset run --cert "PATH_CERT" --key "PATH_KEY" -p "PORT" -h "IpAddress" "

Comment: @gnc you should put that as its own answer in ```